# Shortening of Youtube playlist URL

Tags: python, api, automation, youtube

I'm trying to automate a youtube description with python, and I'd like to shorten a youtube playlist URL.

Normally a non-playlist URL goes [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%7Bvideo_id%7D) and can be shortened to youtu.be/{video_id}.

A playlist URL goes [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}&list=..](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%7Bvideo_id%7D&list=..). and shortening it to youtu.be/{video_id} responds with a non-playlist page.

An alternative I found is to use other websites and convert to URL 3rd-party-domain/{alias-name}. However, I've been informed this isn't ideal as youtube doesn't like other references and that it would hurt the video ranking (not too familiar with these).

So, as the title goes, how do we shorten a Youtube playlist URL preferably with a youtube domain?

Comment: Have you tried to access YT data API?

Comment: I might not understand something, why don't use youtu.be/{video_id}?list={playlist_id}, it's too long?

Comment: @MufasaChan that is actually what I'm looking for. Thanks. If there is any other shorter, then all the better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this site

tinyurl .com

stackoverflow won't let me post the website

I hope this doesn't affect video ranking.